# Mercury Editor with rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mercury-editor

i'm wondering how to use mercury gem with rails4.
i tried to follow guide http://asciicasts.com/episodes/296-mercury-editor
if i load page within editor ( /editor/pages/1) i see **error in javascript console**:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'konqueror' of undefined

and mercury-region isn't visible at page at all

Gemfile:

```
gem 'mercury-rails', github: 'jejacks0n/mercury'
```

app/views/pages/show.html.erb:

```
<div id="page_body" class="mercury-region" data-type="editable">
  <%= raw(@page.body) %>
</div>
```

after some delay i get javascript alert with message:

> Mercury.PageEditor failed to load: Region type is malformed, no data-type provided, or "Full" is unknown for the "page_body" region.
>
> Please try refreshing.

Answer (score 4):

mercury is utilising jquery.browser this method is deprecated in the most recent update.

If you include gem 'jquery-migrate-rails' in your gemfile that you should work favourably until mercury updates it's code to the latest jquery or at least 1.9

You'll need to add
//= require jquery-migrate-min
to your application.js after jquery is loaded.

Comment: I haven't looked at the gem, but in general you shouldn't *need* to include minified scripts in your manifests. Sprockets minifies for you.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same issue.  I describe it better [in my own question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18411316/mercury-rials-no-editable-area-js-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-propert), but basically the issue comes from a deprecated jquery method calling 'konqueror'.  I don't think it had anything to do with your app being in rails 4 btw. I'm in `gem 'rails', '3.2.13'`

I'd up-vote the question but apparently I need more reputation. hint, hint :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with this because of turbolinks. I just disabled its JS in applications.js:

```
//= require turbolinks
```

~to:

```
// require turbolinks
```

-until I figure out how to get them to play nicely together. At least for the Mercury pages, have to poke them somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I have some issues too, it does seem to be an issue with Turbolinks. I was able to get by it by removing the line:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

from my application.html.erb file, not sure if this will cause issues down the road