# mercury-rails no editable area js error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'konqueror' of undefined '

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mercury-editor

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this isn't working!
I'm working through the [railscast for mercury](http://railscasts.com/episodes/296-mercury-editor?view=asciicast) and I can't get the editable area to show up.

gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'mercury-rails', git: 'https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury.git'
gem 'sqlite3'
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

routes

```
MercuryRelational::Application.routes.draw do
  mount Mercury::Engine => '/'

  root to: "pages#show"
```

show page

```
<h1>Show Page</h1>
<div id="page_content" class="mercury-region" data-type="editable"><%= raw(@page.content)     %></div>
```

url to the show page is 
`http://localhost:4002/editor`

still there is no editable blue box around the text.

However!  I do get an error in the javascript terminal though
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'konqueror' of undefined"

Please help!

Comment: Does it work with rails4?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found the problem and have **solved it in the following way!**

It turns out that mercury is using the jquery method [`jQuery.browser`](https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury/blob/3ef7fce91cdc72a6af31519e7a205d92cfebfed5/app/assets/javascripts/mercury/regions/full.js.coffee#L3), which is [deprecated](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed)
 in the jquery 1.9 upgrade.

I'm using `gem 'mercury-rails', git: 'git://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury'`
so this will probably get fixed and I don't know how else to document if this solution is relevant to you, but this is the latest commit I'm using from the mercury gem, `d065b2c31b895af03749254b521f0c0ee18fb25a`.

Including this gem solved the issue for me.

`gem 'jquery-migrate-rails'`

and don't forget `//= require jquery-migrate-min` in the application.js file, after requiring the other jquery files.

Comment: I haven't looked at the gem, but in general you shouldn't need to include minified scripts in your manifests. Sprockets minifies for you.

Comment: @jrhorn424 true, but in this case the gems documentation suggests that as the name of the file to require.  I figure they built it, so I should listen to them :)

Answer (score 3):

I have same issue here by following railscast for mercury.

after re-read mercury documentation on the mercury js file, then i found a solution by changing :

```
<span id="page_name" class="mercury-region" data-type="editable">
```

to

```
<span id="page_name" data-mercury="full" contenteditable="true">
```

hope this will works properly with same issue

Answer (score 0):

I found [issue with Slim engine](https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury/pull/442) and it can be related.
Since mercury ships with query version that it need(1.7), just make sure that `mercury.html.(slim|erb|haml)` that in `app/views/layouts` use that version. Of course this is just for iframe implementation technique